# what to import to resolve "LayoutParams cannot be resolved to a variable"?

Tags: android-layout, layoutparams, resolve

I am getting error `LayoutParams cannot be resolved to a variable` on a line of code which is as follows `tv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0.1f));`
When i press ctrl+shift+o to import necessary pacakges i get a lot of versions of the package as options. I am confused which one should do the job. 
[here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6uVppl6jij2eVllaVhTZVlmZnc/edit?usp=sharing) are the options i get

after importing `import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;` is still get error

```
The constructor AbsListView.LayoutParams(int, int, float) is undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be solved by importing [any layout].LayoutParams 
eg. 
`import android.widget.GridLayout.LayoutParams;`
Although its not clear to me what should be the criteria to choose which package to import.
To solve the problem

```
the constructor AbsListView.LayoutParams(int, int, float) is undefined
```

make sure the third argument is also an "int" 
it should be :

```
LayoutParams cannot be resolved to a variable on a line of code which is as follows tv.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the following statement to use LayoutParams with LinearLayout:

```
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
```

and then you can easily write the following code:

```
LinearLayout ll1;    
LayoutParams params1;

/*Creating a linear layout*/

ll1=new LinearLayout(this);
ll1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
/*set the width and height of the linear layout*/

params1=new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
setContentView(ll1,params1);
```